# Run batch script at first logon in Windows automated Installation

Tags: deployment, windows-10, automated-install, unattended, answer-file

I am doing unattended Windows installation with few initialization script having setups to install like python and java.
I added the script path under FirstLogonCommands as shown here [FirstLogon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umSg5.jpg)

Whenever the Windows is about to complete, the First logon script fails to run because of unavailability of network when the screen with message "**Getting Windows Ready**" comes.

Is there any entries in Unattend.xml to trigger the scripts only when the Windows 10 get installed completely?
I have put a delay of 5 minutes before the Script gets triggered and it works sometimes but now always.

Comment: you can try as workaround RequiresUserInput , if applicable.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands-synchronouscommand-requiresuserinput

Comment: I tried, but didn't help.